# Does FOL extended with least-fixed points satisfy the Compactness Theorem?

Tags: first-order-logic, descriptive-complexity

I am aware that first-order logics (FOL) satisfies the compactness theorem. That is, if a FOL theory is insatisfiable, a finite subset of the axioms of such theory is insatisfiable too.

Is it the case that FOL extended with least-fixed point (LFP) satisfies the compactness theorem too?

Comment: Chapter 4 of these [lecture notes](https://logic.rwth-aachen.de/files/AMT-WS13/script.pdf) indicates that the answer is negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not satisfy compactness anymore.

Least fixed point operators can let us define, for example, the standard part of a model of $\mathsf{PA}$. The standard part of a model $\mathfrak{A}=(A;+^\mathfrak{A},\times^\mathfrak{A},0^\mathfrak{A},1^\mathfrak{A})$ of $\mathsf{PA}$ is just the smallest subset of $A$ containing $0^\mathfrak{A}$ and closed under $n\mapsto n+^\mathfrak{A}1^\mathfrak{A}$. But this is exactly a least fixed point definition: the standard part of $\mathfrak{A}$ is the least fixed point of the operator $$\Phi(P): x=0\vee\exists y(P(y)\wedge y+1=x).$$

This in turn lets us pin down the standard model of $\mathsf{PA}$ up to isomorphism by the theory $\mathsf{PA}$ + "Every element is standard." But this contradicts compactness: no compact logic can ever pin down an infinite structure up to isomorphism (this is really just the observation that the [upwards Lowenheim-Skolem theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem#Upward_part) is just a compactness corollary).

Comment: Hi @noah-schweber, many thanks for your answer. If I understand you correctly, you say that a theory that only has just one (infinite) model do not satisfy compactness, I am trying to see why this is the case.

I suppose that, in this particular example, you might be able to extend PA+{every number is standard} with some other axioms that might make it insat (whereas any finite subset of such axioms would be sat). However, I do not see how you can "kill" the standard arithmetic model with some infinite set of axioms. Can you help me on this, please?

Comment: @441Juggler Sorry, I just saw this. This is a standard trick for applying compactness - **expand the language**. Consider the language of $\mathsf{PA}$ augmented by a new constant symbol $c$, and let $T$ be the theory gotten by adding to $\mathsf{PA}$ each sentence of the form $c>\underline{n}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, where $\underline{n}$ is the numeral corresponding to $n$ (so e.g. $\underline{3}$ is the term $(1+1)+1$). Then $T$ is finitely consistent, hence satisfiable, but if we let $M$ be a model of $T$ then $M$ *(or rather, $M$'s reduct to the language of arithmetic)* must be nonstandard.